# How to call an Excel VBA function, when the function's name is in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an XLS that retrieves a list of dynamically generated reports:

```
    B  |   C  |   D  |   E  |   F  |   G         |   H  |   I  |   J
1   1  |  Bob |Jones |bjones| rep 1|Sales Report | Desc.|   X  |  fnGenerateSalesReport
2   1  |  Bob |Jones |bjones| rep 2|Revenue Rep. | Desc.|   _  |  fnGenerateRevenueReport
3   1  |  Bob |Jones |bjones| rep 3|Customer List| Desc.|   _  |  fnGenerateCustReport
4   1  |  Bob |Jones |bjones| rep 4|Stock Report | Desc.|   _  |  fnGenerateStockReport
```

The user marks X next to the report (column I) they wish to generate and presses a 'GENERATE' button.  How do I get the relevant function to run based on the users selection.  The name of the relevant function (one function per report) is listed in a specific column (Col J) in the list of reports (see below).

At the `debug.print` line I want it to call the function with the dynamic value held in `c.Offset(0, 1).Value`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, stRows As Long
Dim c As Range

Set ws = Sheets("AVAILABLE REPORTS")

Set rng = ws.Range("B12:B12")
Set rng = ws.Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
stRows = rng.Rows.Count

Set rng = ws.Range("I12:I12")
Set rng = ws.Range("I12:I" & 11 + stRows)


For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value = "X" Or c.Value = "x" Then
       Debug.Print "> [" & c.Value & " (" & c.Offset(0, 1).Value & ")]"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of `c.Value` and `c.Offset(0, 1).Value`?

Comment: rng is a range of one or more cells (in a continuous column) which are blank.  The user enters an 'X' and hits a button.  The code above iterates through each of these cells `c` in the range `rng`.  When it finds an 'x', it checks the c.offset(0,1) or the cell to the right of it.  That cell contains a string which is the name of the function that must be run.

Comment: Take a look at edited answer below given by me. Post comments if you find that it isn't working.

Comment: If you have the name of the function in a variable, say `fncName` then `Application.Run fncName` will run the function. You should qualify the full path to the workbook though - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220716(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @ooo  Can you post that as an answer and I'll accept, thanks, far simpler lol

Comment: @aSystemOverload: See the edited example below.

Answer (score 3):

```
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value = "X" Or c.Value = "x" Then
       CallByName myReportGenerator, "GenerateReport", vbMethod, c.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next
```

Note: I am assuming that `myReportGenerator` is a instance of a class that holds the method `GenerateReport` which takes 1 parameter.

**EDIT**: If it works with you, place the functions inside a sheet (say `Sheet1`).
`CallByName Sheet1, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, vbMethod`

The assumption is that the `c.Offset(0, 1).Value` contains the method name which is a `public` method inside `Sheet1`.

**EDIT2**: Assuming you have placed this methods inside a class named `class1`.
Here is what you'll do

```
dim reportHelper as Class1
set reportHelper = new Class1

CallByName reportHelper, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, vbMethod
```

Comment: I've not been that organised, `c.Offset(0, 1).Value` contains a single string which is a standalone function

Comment: @aSystemOverload: No problem. I assume that the functions are part of a module. If it doesn't affect anything else, place it inside a class or `Sheet1` or `ThisWorkbook`. And change the `CallByName ThisWorkbook, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, vbMethod` to `CallByName Sheet1, c.Offset(0, 1).Value, vbMethod` (if you place the functions in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: What is the first argument if I place them in a class module?  I tried `class1`, `"class1"` and `cl` which was a `dim as class1`, none of which work.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative suggestion:

Have you thought about calling ONE function with a "relevant function"-name as a parameter?

You could then just make a `SELECT CASE` to call this relevant function then and you are able to handle input errors, in case the realevant function name was faultive.

```
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value like "X" Then
       CallRelevantFunction c.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next
```

`CallRelevantFunction` can even have multiple parameters if necessary.

```
CallRelevantFunction ("rep 1", "fnGenerateSalesReport")
```

In the end, as long as you are not creating your report generating functions dynamically, I would reconsider your design approach. Because, when the report functions are static, then you can only choose between a defined set of them.

Comment: An advantage of this approach is that `CallRelevantFunction` could run of column G and column J could be discarded.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the name of a Function (or a Sub) stored in a variable you can use the `Run Method` - see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220716%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

eg if variable `fncName = ws.Range("J1").value`

then you can call the function using

```
Application.Run fncName
```

If your function/sub requires arguments this method allows up to 30. Try and give the full path of the workbook, module and function name to avoid any potential conflicts. It's then possible to call functions across any workbook without fear of conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

An `EVALUATE` <s>function</s> method would probably be of use:

```
debug.Print Sheet2.Cells(1,1).Value
Day(Now())&Month(Now())&Year(Now())

Debug.Print Evaluate(Sheet2.Cells(1,1).Value)
2792012
```

Comment: Well that seems to run through part of the code, as it displays some MSGBOXs, but it doesn't retrieve records or display worksheets the code tells it to??!?! : - S

Comment: @aSystemOverload can you give a sample?